# undefined symbol: sqlite3_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

When I try to deploy my Rails application to an Apache server using Passenger, I get the following error in the logs:

```
undefined symbol: sqlite3_initialize
```

I get the same error when just running webrick using "rails s". How do I fix this? I'm using the latest Rails 3.0.9 and whatever the default SQLite is when running bundle install

Comment: Can you post the entire section of your log?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something is getting in the way of your application from loading libsqlite3.so.0. Was the shared library bundled with your Rails app? If not, you can just install libsqlite3 from a repository.

In CentOS or RedHat Linux, you can install it with:

```
yum install libsqlite3x
```

In Debian or Ubuntu Server you can use:

```
apt-get install libsqlite3-0
```